# Setter for computed property of type Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, getter-setter, computed-properties

I am new to swift and I am using swift 4.0. I have a class with computed property of type Dictionary. I am using getter and setter for this property. Below is my property snippet.

```
var responses:[String:Float] {
    get {
        let newresponses = self.calculateResponses(with: self.Range)
        return newresponses
    }
    set {

    }
}
```

How do I code setter so it allows me to update value for specific key? For example, in one of my func I need to update value for responses for a specific key.

```
self. responses[key] = newResponse
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with computed property. Because every time you're trying to get `responses` you're actually getting result of  `self.calculateResponses(with: self.Range)`.

To solve this just create empty dictionary

```
var responses = [String : Float]()
```

and then when you need to assign new value use this

```
responses[key] = newResponse
```

or if you need to assign all new dictionary use this

```
responses = self.calculateResponses(with: self.Range)
```